# UTF-8 in MySQL: Both precise string comparison and caseless fulltext search possible?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, full-text-search

Through research and testing, I have found that it seems that the most equal behavior to a latin charset exists if one uses utf8_bin encoding for fields (guarantees accurate string comparison) and converts the collation to e.g. utf8_general_ci in "order by" clauses.

However, I can't find a workaround to make caseless fulltext search work, since there is neither collation conversion, nor does it seem one can use "lower" on the fulltext key.

Considering what I've read about this whole topic so far, this might be like having your cake and eating it too but I figured I'd ask before I go back to latin charset and drop international support from my website.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports full "perl-style" regular expressions, so you should be able to specify case-independence in the search term: `WHERE field RLIKE '(?i)search term'`. Can't say for sure but it ought to work with utf-8.

Edit: `(?i)` and its kin are not mentioned in the MySQL page, so this might be a non-starter.

Comment: Well, I guess I could look for "uppercase|lowercase" for every character in the search term. I'm just worried about the speed of this with texts containing many thousand words.

Comment: Regular expression searches are computationally efficient (if you don't need lots of back-tracking, which single-letter alternatives don't), so really they ought to be faster than any collation that needs to follow a lot of complex rules. I'd say give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I have now tested many variations based on alexis' tip regarding regular expressions and for the sake of other people dealing with this problem, I figured I should share my findings.

The in my view best solution upfront: use lower() on binary utf-8 fields in combination with regular expressions looking for whole keywords.
At least as far as solutions with one table are concerned. I think in the end, my answer to the original question will be to have two tables. One that contains all texts in lower case format and is used for the fulltext search and one that contains the texts as they are displayed to users. Twice the amount of data but the queries with boolean search will take a lot less time to finish.

First, the non-binary table with fulltext index as point of reference:

```
SELECT * FROM texts WHERE MATCH (text1, text2, text3, text4) AGAINST ('psycho' in boolean mode) 
Query took 0.0003 sec
```

The fastest solution for binary:

```
SELECT * FROM texts_bin WHERE lower(text1) rlike 'psycho' OR lower(text2) rlike 'psycho' OR lower(text3) rlike 'psycho' OR lower(text4) rlike 'psycho'
Query took 0.0014 sec
```

Plus - other tests I conducted which may be helpful:

```
SELECT * FROM texts_bin WHERE lower(text1) like '%psycho%' OR lower(text2) like '%psycho%' OR lower(text3) like '%psycho%' OR lower(text4) like '%psycho%'
Query took 0.0023 sec

SELECT * FROM texts_bin WHERE text1 REGEXP '(P|p)(S|s)(Y|y)(C|c)(H|h)(O|o)' OR text2 REGEXP '(P|p)(S|s)(Y|y)(C|c)(H|h)(O|o)' OR text3 REGEXP '(P|p)(S|s)(Y|y)(C|c)(H|h)(O|o)' OR text4 REGEXP '(P|p)(S|s)(Y|y)(C|c)(H|h)(O|o)'
Query took 0.0282 sec
```